# How can I have voted 41 times in a day

Tags: support, voting

The voting limits are well known to me and are also [well explained on meta.so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits):

> Post votes (votes on questions and answers)
>
> - Thirty post votes per day per user (includes upvotes and downvotes)
> - Up to ten additional question-only votes per day per user. These may be cast at any time during the day, but the exact number you get
>     [depends on your voting behavior for the day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256).

I've reached that limit many times before. Much to my surprise today I could vote 41 times in total before I reached the limit:

[image]

How can that be?

Comment: I wish I could vote 41 times. `:)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The votes per day limit is based on the calendar day. The number of votes casted refers to the last 24 hours afaik.

Another possibility is that votes were cast on questions which have been deleted. It would allow to vote again. But your *votes cast* number would not be decreased, for example to not penalize for downvoting bad questions which were deleted later.

Comment: No, unless they've changed it the number is reset to 0 at 1:00 or 2:00 CET (I can't remember right now). It's always the same. But I didn't think of possibly deleted posts. Thanks.

Comment: Source regarding the 24 hours: [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113044/how-do-i-get-more-than-40-votes-per-day).

Comment: I see... My screenshot is not from my review stats, though, but the dropdown menu you see when you hover over your name at the top of the page. As far as I remember it has always been in sync with the actual resetting.

Comment: In that case it might be the other possibility. Did you find a post which has been deleted and you have voted on it?

Comment: That must be it ([this post on meta.so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day?lq=1) suggests the same), although I'm not able to find it. Doesn't matter...