# 39 votes, and I can't use my last vote!

Tags: support

Life is unfair. While some people can vote [41 times a day](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/how-can-i-have-voted-41-times-in-a-day), now for whatever reason I can't use my last vote, so I'm stuck at 39! It's a tragedy! `:)`

> [tohecz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11002/tohecz): Paulo's profile is a good calendar: `(# of votes in month)/40 = (day of month)`

I'm pretty sure I already spent all my 40 votes today (you guys know me). I suspect some question/answer got deleted, so one of my votes got subtracted, but since I reached the vote cap, the system won't allow me to vote anymore.

[image: See]

Of course, you guys know I'm just teasing about this tragedy thingy. `:)` But it might be an odd behaviour in the vote system that is worth mentioning.

On the other hand, I suspect this is a plot from CHAOS. They don't want me to become to top voter of the entire SO universe! `:)`

But the vote shall prevail!

---

In other news, if you came here expecting a duck, here it is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{cd4aa00}{RGB}{212,170,0}
\definecolor{cffffff}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{c0055d4}{RGB}{0,85,212}

\newcommand{\drawdolan}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.8pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
    (445.0141,295.5803) .. controls (463.5305,240.9192) and (454.4385,195.2341) ..
    (365.9156,193.8680) .. controls (292.1854,192.7302) and (262.8579,232.0923) ..
    (279.3875,295.0072);
  \path[draw=black,fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
    (341.5039,238.4289) .. controls (332.1253,220.9287) and (322.6306,229.2505) ..
    (321.1556,244.9886) .. controls (328.9835,244.1457) and (336.1615,242.4674) ..
    (341.5039,238.4289) -- cycle;
  \path[draw=black,fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
    (413.5263,243.1144) .. controls (405.2678,222.8996) and (392.5440,221.7536) ..
    (386.7522,244.3192) .. controls (394.7478,246.3953) and (403.3963,246.7300) ..
    (413.5263,243.1144) -- cycle;
  \path[draw=black,fill=cd4aa00,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
    (377.4939,238.2485) .. controls (369.5553,222.0786) and (354.9417,218.9314) ..
    (348.4466,231.7746) .. controls (341.9514,244.6177) and (303.7917,245.9276) ..
    (301.7810,249.3394) .. controls (299.7702,252.7513) and (314.7322,267.7970) ..
    (330.9722,263.6722) .. controls (347.2121,259.5474) and (364.7537,258.1146) ..
    (377.4462,263.4493) .. controls (390.1387,268.7840) and (424.8168,254.2696) ..
    (426.4731,245.0782) .. controls (428.1293,235.8868) and (385.4325,254.4184) ..
    (377.4939,238.2485) -- cycle;
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
    (426.0836,243.5881) .. controls (427.0979,245.2552) and (377.1067,256.6520) ..
    (368.9778,250.8053) .. controls (360.8489,244.9586) and (340.7970,246.2939) ..
    (328.1915,253.4427) .. controls (315.3039,260.7516) and (302.6701,252.8802) ..
    (302.6701,252.8802);
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
    (349.6700,230.1290) .. controls (335.4480,204.9114) and (310.7246,220.9973) ..
    (314.1943,246.1934);
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
    (422.7634,242.1773) .. controls (413.5091,220.8054) and (408.3388,213.2803) ..
    (397.4418,213.8281) .. controls (389.9529,214.2045) and (375.7048,226.0488) ..
    (380.0586,241.3741);
  \path[draw=black,fill=c0055d4,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
    (293.1317,215.7142) .. controls (293.1317,215.7142) and (287.8425,171.6175) ..
    (302.3289,159.3589) .. controls (316.8152,147.1003) and (336.6158,130.7821) ..
    (365.9770,164.5022) .. controls (392.0467,143.3431) and (420.5172,153.1700) ..
    (423.0354,165.4666) .. controls (425.4417,183.3961) and (420.1479,199.7909) ..
    (415.8026,201.3089) .. controls (366.4059,186.8904) and (311.2758,194.7582) ..
    (293.1317,215.7142) -- cycle;
  \path[draw=black,fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
    (354.8868,153.4120) .. controls (354.8868,153.4120) and (351.9602,136.3002) ..
    (352.4759,134.1247) .. controls (352.9916,131.9492) and (364.8519,137.0178) ..
    (364.8519,137.0178) .. controls (364.8519,137.0178) and (371.0489,128.9214) ..
    (373.3281,129.9864) .. controls (375.6073,131.0513) and (374.6614,158.1137) ..
    (375.2568,158.1137) -- (366.2985,164.8237) -- cycle;
  \path[draw=black,fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
    (292.2476,199.2222) .. controls (330.8168,174.1143) and (373.7998,170.6750) ..
    (422.1713,188.2359) .. controls (420.7175,193.3193) and (418.0585,201.5582) ..
    (415.0326,201.1565) .. controls (371.2234,185.1974) and (315.1797,195.1857) ..
    (293.2902,214.8016) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\dolan}[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\drawdolan\\[2em]
{\bfseries\sffamily\Huge #1}
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\centering

\dolan{chaos pls}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: chaos pls]

`:)`

Comment: I am pretty sure you won't only be able to find out the day of the month but also when is morning over there in Brazil :) The votes are most likely all gone by 9 o'clock in the morning (Brazil time).

Comment: @topskip: ooh! `:)`

Comment: So were you going to vote for @egreg or me on that one? If the former it doesn't matter, if the latter I agree it's a tragedy that you were not allowed to vote.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I was going to upvote the question today (vote cap), then tomorrow I would upvote both answers. `:)`

Comment: I have had that quite often, sometimes even stuck at 36 or 37...

Comment: @cgnieder: Oh my! `:)` But I never got 41, I'm sad. `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, some of us are gifted, some of us work hard :)

[image]

I have no idea what this system keeps track of.

Comment: [Noooooooo!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWaLxFIVX1s) `:)`

Answer (score 8):

Once you vote on 30 answers, you cannot vote, answers or questions. That's one (maybe the only one) reason not to be able to use 40 votes.

Comment: Actually, the algorithm says that if you are able to vote for 31 "posts", you are able to reach 40. The vote balance only happens when you are below 30 votes a day. I've mapped the algorithm's behaviour for quite a time. `:)`