# Maximum daily vote: 41 today and 39 yesterday?

Tags: support, voting, voting-limits, rate-limiting

Yesterday somehow I can only vote 39 times, and today it has just told me that I have voted 41 times so I'm not allowed to vote anymore until tomorrow:

[image]

You can see that by a simple subtraction: yesterday = this week (today & yesterday) − today = 80 − 41 = 39.

How can this be possible?

I have seen [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3309/39-votes-and-i-cant-use-my-last-vote) and [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/how-can-i-have-voted-41-times-in-a-day) but I still can't figure out what happened to me :) Or did the site notice that yesterday it made a mistake so today it gives my vote back?

Comment: I suspect it depends on the time zone.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I don't think so. Actually I can't vote anymore until 7:00 am tomorrow (local time) or 0:00 am tomorrow UTC time. I _did_ test it: reputation, vote count, badges, leagues, etc. are all depended on UTC time, not local time.

Comment: I don't know, then

Comment: @JouleV: Were you able to corroborate the voting counts for questions *vs* answers?

Comment: @Werner I don't really count the number of votes for questions and answers _individually_, but generally I think votes on questions take up to 45% of my total votes. It has been 45% for very long.

Comment: @JouleV: Sure. It would just be interesting to confirm my suspicions listed below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are rate-limits with voting. While the default user usually maxes out at 40, there are times when you can "max out" under 40, or even exceed this limit. You'll be vote-limited if you only (mostly) vote on answers. This could lead to you not being able to cast 40 votes. Also casting more is possible when posts you voted on are deleted.

Since voting is private, you should be able to go back and look at [your votes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/156344/joulev?tab=votes&sort=all) (only the [upvotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/156344/joulev?tab=votes&sort=upvotes)/[downvotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/156344/joulev?tab=votes&sort=downvotes)) and count them by question type.

Here is an excerpt from the linked reference:

- 30 votes per day +10 for questions only (Q only votes can't be used after 25 votes cast on answers. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/168244))
- If one of the posts you vote on gets deleted the same day as you vote, your limit is recalculated as if you never cast that vote (i.e. in most cases, you can cast one more vote in this case).
- If you vote and undo your vote 30 times, your vote gets locked in.

[image]

References:

- [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/168244)
- [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/168244)

Answer (score 3):

This meta.SE question explains how you can get more than the maximum 40 votes per day:

[How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day)

When you get less than 40 votes/day, it's because you didn't maintain a high enough ratio of question votes to answer votes, as mentioned here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279732/130540